# Dexie not a function in where clause

Tags: where-clause, dexie

I'm trying to query a Dexie DB to retrieve the top 25 most used items from a language-specific collection, below is the code and the issue I have found.

TABLE Schema:

```
myTable: 
      ++id,
      name,
      lang,
      lastUse,
      counter,
      [lang+counter],
      type,
      groupID,
      category_id,
      subcategory_id`
```

QUERY:

```
collection_result = dexieDB.myTable.where('lang').equals(`${active_language}`).reverse().sortBy('lastUse').limit(25);
collection_result.toArray();
```

ISSUE found:

```
caught (in promise) TypeError: dexieDB.myTable.where(...).equals(...).reverse(...).sortBy(...).limit is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Collection.orderBy(), Collection.sortBy() returns a promise directly with the results so there's unfortunately no option to add a limit.

But good news is you can both query and sort using a native index instead.

1. Add the index '[lang+lastUse]'
2. Do the following query:

   ```
   dexieDB.myTable
     .where('[lang+lastUse]')
     .between(
       [active_language, Dexie.minKey],
       [active_language, Dexie.maxKey])
     .reverse()
     .limit(25)
     .toArray();
   ```

Reason you get it sorted by lastUse is that IndexedDB will always sort by the queried index, and the index we use is a compound index that includes the lastUse property. The `.reverse()` will make it sort in reverse order.